# Is the HEAD response faster than the GET?

Tags: http-get, http-verbs, http-head

I'm currently getting the info about the files with GET, will it be faster if I rewrite it using HEAD request? Cause I close the connection after the first response.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

A HEAD response only includes the HTTP headers but no body - it is generally faster to just use a HEAD if you do not use any information in the body that would have normally transferred in a GET response - if there was no body to begin with it should not make a difference.

Also from [here](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec9.html):

> **The HEAD method is identical to GET except that the server MUST NOT
>   return a message-body in the response.** The metainformation contained
>   in the HTTP headers in response to a HEAD request SHOULD be identical
>   to the information sent in response to a GET request. This method can
>   be used for obtaining metainformation about the entity implied by the
>   request without transferring the entity-body itself. This method is
>   often used for testing hypertext links for validity, accessibility,
>   and recent modification.

Comment: I saw that the server sometimes don't support HEAD and returns error 405. So I'll stick with GET.

Answer (score 4):

Whether `HEAD` is faster than `GET` depends purely on the implementation of the server-side (it usually is due to less data transfer)... IF the information `HEAD` delivers is sufficient in your case I would go with `HEAD` and only fallback to `GET` where `HEAD` is not implemented properly and/or some obscure proxy is messing with it...

Answer (score 2):

You haven't given any information about the type of server you're accessing or network you're accessing it over.

It is indeed plausible that a HEAD request would complete faster than GET, since it involves less data transfer.  However, on a fast or high latency connection this almost always won't matter.  As for the server side, it really depends heavily on what you're doing, but in most circumstances there would be no measurable difference if you timed it.

If you don't need the body of the response, why not use HEAD anyway?  Regardless of whether you can measure any difference in response time or you can't, it is more bandwidth-efficient.

Answer (score 2):

It's probably negligible. It really depends what the server is doing. Once it receives a request, you can't guarantee to expect a response from a HEAD request or a GET request any quicker than the other.

In theory, because the response to a HEAD request should be the same as that of a GET request, but without the response body, it *should* be quicker because its transfering less data. But there is no guaruntee that one connection which processes a HEAD request will be any quicker than another connection processing a GET request.

Answer (score 2):

The important thing to note with your question, is that you are talking about 'GET requests and HEAD requests' - instead of 'GET responses, and HEAD responses'

Logically - the request for a HEAD and a GET both take the same amount of time to travel from your PC to the server destination. Whatever that server does with the HEAD/GET will be up to the server owner, so they could make a HEAD take longer if they coded it to do so.
If you really want to get into semantics, you could argue that a HEAD request is one extra character of data than a GET request, therefore, a HEAD request technically has to transmit 1 byte more of data in the request phase. In practice, this is going to be an non-measurable difference in request time.

If you were to start a timer from the moment both 'RESPONSES' left the server on their way back to the requester, then logically speaking, a GET response will take longer to travel across the network. Since it will usually consist of HEADERS and BODY - the BODY can be a huge amount of data.

A Head response will take less time to travel, because it is just HEADERS.
Using a really extreme example - if you send a GET request for a 4GB file, it will take minutes for that GET response to finish writing the data to your network stream.
A HEAD request for the same 4GB file will finish almost instantly, because it is only sending information that describes the 4GB file at a high level, without having to transmit its contents to the requester.

> A GET response will encompass a HEAD + BODY.
>   A HEAD response will contain the HTTP Headers only.

I personally use HEAD requests in combination with a technology called IPFS - which is a type of distributed internet, where files and data can be stored on a P2P network. In order to keep files alive on the network, they need to be requested frequently. However, if you pull the file via a GET request, you end up using bandwidth, to download that 4GB file you stored weeks ago.
Performing a HEAD request however, in my case, keeps the file alive on the network, but does not request the 4GB of data to travel to me on the network.