# What's the fastest way to check the file type of large list of URLs (and how to optimize my code)

Tags: .net, http, network-programming, c#-2.0

I have a large list (expanding over time) of URLs that I need to check their type. That's the code I currently have:

```
    private string[] MIME = new string[] {
        "audio/ogg - ogg",
        "video/ogg - ogg",
        "application/f4v - mp4",
        "application/octet-stream - mp3",
        "audio/aac - mp3",
        "audio/mp3 - mp3",
        "audio/mp4 - mp4",
        "audio/mp4-latm - m4a",
        "audio/mpeg - mp3",
        "audio/mpeg3 - mp3",
        "audio/x-mpeg - mp3",
        "audio/x-ms-wma - wma",
        "video/f4v - mp4",
        "video/mp4 - mp4",
    };


    private string CheckType(string url) {
        try {
            HttpWebRequest webRequest = (HttpWebRequest) WebRequest.Create(new Uri(url));

            webRequest.UserAgent = "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; rv:2.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/4.0";
            webRequest.Accept = "text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8";
            webRequest.Timeout = 5000;

            HttpWebResponse webResponse = (HttpWebResponse) webRequest.GetResponse();
            long fileSize = webResponse.ContentLength;

            foreach (string mime_entry in MIME) {
                string sheader = webResponse.Headers.ToString();
                string[] mime = mime_entry.Split(new string[] { " - " }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);

                if (sheader.Contains(mime[0])) {
                    return mime[1] + " " + fileSize.ToString();
                }
            }

            return "";
        } catch (Exception ex) {
            return "";
        }
    }
```

1. Can I make my request faster?
2. Can I somehow use multi-threading to iterate the list faster (what if one of the threads halts because of the http response?)
3. Is there a better way to do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Yes, you can make this faster by only issuing HEAD requests, since, after all, you don't use the response body for anything.
2. Yes, it would make good sense to multi-thread this moderately - if the urls are on different servers, there will be server wait times that can be parallellized easily. Use a synchronized queue and some worker threads processing the queue would be an easy way to parallellize this. You can experiment with the number of threads, I'd try 8 threads as a starting point.
3. See above. And also, your MIME-checking code is supoptimal. You can use a `Dictionary<string,string>` for the lookup; and in the `Headers` collection, you should only look at Content-Type, not the whole headers collection.

Comment: I already asked if HEAD is faster than GET. It seems to be the same. And also some servers don't support it. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7132967/is-the-head-response-faster-than-the-get

Comment: HEAD is not likely to be faster in server processing time if it's a dynamic page, but for static resources, it should be faster.