# Pass Data to and Open a ViewController Inside Navigation Controller

Tags: ios, webview

I have a standalone `UIViewController` with a `UIWebView`. I need to check if a certain URL has been hit, and if so, present a new `UIViewController` inside of a `UINavigationController`.

Here is my code:

```
-(BOOL)webView:(UIWebView*)webView shouldStartLoadWithRequest:(NSURLRequest*)request navigationType:(UIWebViewNavigationType)navigationType {

NSURL *url = request.URL;
NSString *urlString = url.absoluteString;

//Check if special link
if ( [ urlString isEqualToString: @"http://www.mysite.com/store" ] ) {
    //Here present the new view controller
    StoreViewController *controller = [[StoreViewController alloc] init];
    [self presentViewController:controller animated:YES completion: nil];

    return NO;
}

    return YES;

}
```

However, when I run the app, I get the following error:

> WebKit threw an uncaught exception in the method
>   webView:decidePolicyForNavigationAction:request:frame:decisionListener:
>   delegate:
>
> <'NSInvalidArgumentException'> *** -[__NSArrayM insertObject:atIndex:]:
>   object cannot be nil

If I try and open the `UINavigationController` itself it works fine...but then how do I pass data to the `StoreViewController` itself?

Comment: The answer(s) here may help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7883899/ios-5-uiwebview-delegate-webkit-discarded-an-uncaught-exception-in-the-webview

Answer (score 0):

Let's try these solutions:

1. Destroy webview's delegate in your view controller:

   ```
   -(void)dealloc{ self.yourWebView.delegate = nil}
   ```
2. Stop request from webView:

   ```
   -(BOOL)webView:(UIWebView*)webView shouldStartLoadWithRequest:(NSURLRequest*)request navigationType:(UIWebViewNavigationType)navigationType {

   StoreViewController *controller = [[StoreViewController alloc] init];
   [self presentViewController:controller animated:YES completion: nil];
   //stop loading here
   [webview stopLoading];
   return NO;
   }
   ```
3. Double check in new view controller, do you have any array which it's element is assigned to nil

Hope this helps you

Answer (score 0):

Lets go through the problems one by one:

- **WebKit Exception**: You can resolve this by stopping the webview loading. Just call `[webView stopLoading];`
- **Pass data**: If you declare your required data in the StoreViewController.h you can easily set them when you are initializing the view controller.

  ```
  StoreViewController *controller = [[StoreViewController alloc] init]; 
  controller.myStringData = @"Required Data"; 
  controller.myDataDictionary = someDictionary;
  ```

  You will be able to get the data in the `viewDidLoad` method of `StoreViewController`

Hope this helps.