# Show image in WebView by URL with cyrillc symbols

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiwebview

I have a URL:

```
 <pre><p><img scr="...upload/tmp/Группа.jpg" border="0" width="300" height="234"/></p>
</pre>
```

but UIWebView does not load the picture because there are Cyrillic symbols.

How can I fix it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your problem is encoding. You will have to specify different encoding since UIWebView by default takes iso-8859-1. I think that you will find solution for this problem on the link :

[How to change the character encoding in UIWebView?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4973096/how-to-change-the-character-encoding-in-uiwebview)

Please check second answer. You need ISO-8859-5 charset ( http://a4esl.org/c/charset.html )

Answer (score 0):

Encode file names using percent encoding.